# How import everything from designated module without get error of flake8

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I want to split my settings.py in django project so I do:

```py
# within __init__py
from .app import *

try:
    from .app.local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

But I get this error from flake8:

```
'from .app import *' used; unable to detect undefined namesflake8(F403)
'.app.*' imported but unusedflake8(F401)
```

How can I solve it?
When I used of importlib.import_module I got  `The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty` error because the 'SECRET_KEY` inserted into the object that returned from importlib.import_module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add `# noqa` every line that I don't want to flake8 check it.

```py
from .app import *  # noqa

try:
    from .app.local_settings import *  # noqa
except ImportError:
    pass
```